Issue with Contact Form 7 Submission due to Conflict with Search and Filter Pro
I’m encountering an issue with Contact Form 7 on my WordPress site. After some investigation, I’ve identified that there’s a conflict between Contact Form 7 and the Search and Filter Pro plugin.
When attempting to submit a form created with Contact Form 7, it fails to submit, and upon checking the browser console, I noticed the following error:

TypeError: t.replace is not a function


This error seems to be originating from the Search and Filter Pro plugin. It appears to be interfering with the functionality of Contact Form 7, preventing form submission.
How to resolve this conflict or any workaround that could help me ensure the smooth functioning of both plugins simultaneously?
https://sheltercymru.org.uk/

You need to check why the Search and Filter Pro plugins are hooking to other form that shouldn't be their plugins. If you are paying for the plugin, ask them for docs to check which hook to the forms, because it supposed to done that.

Also it seems that Seach Optimization Pro are... doing bad things here by Overwriting the replace function on the js                 String.prototype.replaceAll = function(t, e, r) {                     return this.replace(new RegExp(t.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g, "\\$&"),r ? "gi" : "g"), "string" == typeof e ? e.replace(/\$/g, "$$$$") : e)                 }, it's the source of the problem, the r parameter is empty, throwing error.. as Form 7 depends on it..

Use wp_dequeue_script() if you dont need Search and Filter Pro where the form is. And also contact author to fix this issue with replaceAll function.
